# Не загружается файл на сервер

Tags: php, html, mysql

Не загружается аватар на сервер. Делал по [этим урокам](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=350). Т.е. форма с полем для загрузки выглядит так:

```
<form action="save_user.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fupload" size="20" maxlength="255">
</form>
```

Дело в том, что скрипт, приведённый уроках, даже не выполняет загрузку, т.к. условие не выполняется. Элемента fupload в массиве post запроса не вообще. Почему?

Вот сам скрипт проверки существование переменной fupload:

```
if (isset($_POST['fupload'])) {
    $fupload = $_POST['fupload'];
    $fupload = trim($fupload);
    if ($fupload == '') {
        unset($fupload);
    }
}

if (!isset($fupload) or $fupload == '') {
    $avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fupload = isset($_POST['fupload']) ? $_POST['fupload'] : null;
$avatar = is_null($fupload) ? "avatars/net-avatara.jpg" : "Загружен стандартный аватар";
```

сделал вот такое перевоплощение в 2 тернарных оператора :)

Comment: Все равно не работает. Приравнивает постоянно "avatars/net-avatara.jpg";

Comment: Значить $_POST['fupload'] не существует! Напиши на странице save_user.php print_r($_POST); и посмотри что вообще приходит. Если пусто по опечатка наверно где-то

Comment: Вы правы. Глянул - есть все переменные кроме fupload. Но вся фишка в том, что когда я поменял тип поля с file на text, то все все появилось и заработало. Что за фигня? Как это объяснить?

Comment: Для файла существует отдельный массив $_FILES, а у вас был $_POST

Answer (score 1):

для type="file" надо рассматривать массив $_FILES, где каждый элемент имеет ключ - имя из вашего поля input

Answer (score 0):

В вашем же первом примере меняется $_POST['fupload'] на $_FILES['fupload'] — и всё работает.

http://php.su/learnphp/vars/?reserved#post
http://php.su/learnphp/vars/?reserved#files

А ещё посмотрите в сторону массива $_REQUEST. Частенько бывает очень удобно.